# How can I separate one table into several with MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have a simple question for you all. 
I have a table like this one:

```
ID  NAME     CODE
--  -------  ----
1   JIM      14
1   JOHN     26
2   NICK     26
3   GEORGE   14
4   PAUL     14
4   STEPHEN  26
5   KELLY    14
6   JACK     26
```

I want to create 3 tables from the one above. One that includes only the IDs with code 14 that do not have the same id with code 26. One that includes only the IDs with code 26 that do not have the same id with code 14. And one that includes the IDs with code 14 and code 26. To be more precise I want these tables:

- Table 1:

  ```
  ID  NAME    CODE
  --  ------  ----
  3   GEORGE  14
  5   KELLY   14
  ```
- Table 2:

  ```
  ID  NAME  CODE
  --  ----  ----
  2   NICK  26
  6   JACK  26
  ```
- Table 3:

  ```
  ID  NAME     CODE
  --  -------  ----
  1   JIM      14
  1   JOHN     26
  4   PAUL     14
  4   STEPHEN  26
  ```

Thanks in advance for any help guys!

Comment: Do you want make table or want this result from select query?

Answer (score 1):

1st Table:

> CREATE TABLE table1 AS  (select * from table3 as T1 where T1.code=14 
>   AND T1.id NOT IN(select T2.id from table3 as T2 where T1.id=T2.id AND
>   T2.code=26));

2nd Table:

> CREATE TABLE table2 AS  (select * from table3 as T1 where T1.code=26 
>   AND T1.id NOT IN(select T2.id from table3 as T2 where T1.id=T2.id AND
>   T2.code=14));

3rd Table:

> CREATE TABLE table3 AS  (select T1.* from table3 as T1 INNER JOIN
>   table3 as T2  ON T1.id = T2.id AND ((T2.code=26 AND T1.code=14) OR
>   (T2.code=14 AND T1.code=26) ));

Answer (score 1):

Bearing in mind that a `VIEW` is a table:

1.

```
CREATE VIEW Table1
AS
SELECT * 
  FROM YourTable AS T1
 WHERE T1.Code = 14
       AND NOT EXISTS (
                       SELECT * 
                         FROM YourTable AS T2
                        WHERE T2.Name = T1.Name 
                              AND T1.Code = 26
                      );
```

2.

```
CREATE VIEW Table2
AS
SELECT * 
  FROM YourTable AS T1
 WHERE T1.Code = 26
       AND NOT EXISTS (
                       SELECT * 
                         FROM YourTable AS T2
                        WHERE T2.Name = T1.Name 
                              AND T1.Code = 14
                      );
```

3.

```
CREATE VIEW Table3
AS
SELECT * 
  FROM YourTable AS T1
 WHERE T1.Code = 14
       AND EXISTS (
                   SELECT * 
                     FROM YourTable AS T2
                    WHERE T2.Name = T1.Name 
                          AND T1.Code = 26
                  );
```

Note `CREATE VIEW` SQL DDL requires [ANSI-92 Query Mode](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/about-ansi-sql-query-mode-mdb-HP003070483.aspx?redir=0), otherwise just create the above as 'query' objects in the usual way.